# Execute script on a remote server contained on client side

Tags: ssh, scripting, remote, rsh

I am trying to figure out how I could manage more easily my servers. I'd like to know if I can make my scripts available to all the servers without copying them to the servers.

They are located in my computer (client side),

```
bash-3.2$ ls -l my_local_script
-rwxr--r--  1 mario  staff  554 Jan  9 13:35 my_local_script
```

I always login remotely with my terminal using SSH

```
bash-3.2$ ssh root@192.168.56.140
root@192.168.56.140's password:
[root@prodsrvr00 ~]#
```

Once I am logged into the server, I'd like to know if there is any way to execute the script like it was locally available without copying it to the server.

```
[root@prodsrvr00 ~]# my_local_script
```

Since it's a NAT network, I cannot SSH back to my computer (the client).

Comment: `ssh` back is possible. Would it be an option for you?

Comment: I suggest you to take a look to the tool ansible, perhaps it is useful for you: https://github.com/ansible/ansible

Answer (score 5):

To do it after logging into the remote server, do:

> ***`ssh <local_machine_where_script_resides> "cat <Full_path_to_my_local_script>" | bash`***

*replace "bash" with whatever interpreter is required by your script*
*`(I wouldn't recommend this way and prefer below)`*

There is a way to do this without logging into remote machine:

> ***`ssh <remote_machine> "bash -s" -- < ./my_local_script  "Arg1" "Arg2"`***

In your case, it is:

> ***`ssh root@192.168.56.140 "bash -s" -- < ./my_local_script  "Arg1" "Arg2"`***

I would suggest as well to look into options like `puppet`, `chef`, `ansible` etc.,.