# How to execute script on remote server after loggin in through ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm managing a bunch of servers so I frequently have to ssh into them. I'd like to automatically run a basic custom script on whatever remote server after logging in. Say to set up some aliases, colors for vim, PS1, and what-not.

I don't want to configure every server with a startup script, I want this to live locally on my computer and just get executed on whatever server I ssh into.

[There are similar questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336116/execute-script-on-a-remote-server-contained-on-client-side) but after executing the script ssh logs out. How to stay logged in?

[This answer is quite near](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28360598), yet the new `bash -l` does not seem to register the environment variables set like: `ssh -t user@remote 'export PS1=myps1; bash -l'`. Here, PS1 is not set in the new prompt, maybe because some remote .bashrc

How could this be possible?

Comment: This is what the `.bashrc` file is designed for. Can you explain why this does not fulfill your use case?

Comment: Using .bashrc would imply to configure dozens of remote server. I want to execute a script after loggin in to any server. I'd like to be able to change my prompt, for example.

Comment: ... `scp ~/.bashrc user@remote:~/.bashrc && ssh user@remote`

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple:

```
ssh user@10.0.0.7 'bash -s' < local_bash_script.sh
```

After execution of the script `local_bash_script.sh` ssh-session will be closed immediately.

**Update.**

If you want to execute something on a remote server after ssh logging in, just create ssh `rc` file. Create **on remote server** `rc` file inside user's `.ssh` directory:

```
touch ~/.ssh/rc
```

Open the file with your favorite text editor, let it be `nano` for instance:

```
nano ~/.ssh/rc
```

and copy/paste content of the script file:

```
#/bin/sh

date
whoami
uname -r

exit 0
```

Every time during logging in the script will be executed (replace `date`, `whoami`, `uname -r` with your commands).

The script `~/.ssh/rc` will be executed for a definite user who is owner of the directory where the `rc` file resides. If you wish to execute `rc` script for all of the users on remote server, create another global `sshrc` file:

```
/etc/ssh/sshrc
```

That's all.

Comment: If I do that, after executing the script ssh logs out. I wish to set to environment variables in the new server, even changing PS1.

Comment: @arod I have updated my answer according to your comment.

Comment: Thanks Bob. But what I want to avoid is precisely creating any script on remote server (there are potentially hundreds). I want to have the script locally, and just running my local script on the remote server after login through ssh, mostly to set up PS1 to my liking and other alias, and things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Add the needed commands in your `~/.bashrc`.

In case, you'd check the value of `SSH_CLIENT`/`SSH_TTY` to detect if you are connected via ssh.

```
if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ] || [ -n "$SSH_TTY" ]; then ... ; fi
```

Check [How can I detect if the shell is controlled from SSH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/how-can-i-detect-if-the-shell-is-controlled-from-ssh#9607) for more details

Comment: Thanks but what I want to avoid is precisely creating any script on remote server (there are potentially hundreds). I want to have the script locally, and just running my local script on the remote server after login through ssh, mostly to set up PS1 to my liking and other alias, and things like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1347560).

Since I'm using iTerm2, I came up with:

You can also have a script like `~/test.py`

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

print("echo hello world")
```

And then execute this script as a co-process in iTerm2 menu Session->Run Co-Process, and specifying the script as `~/test.py`

I think its necessary to make you script executable (though I haven't tried otherwise), `chmod +x ~/test.py`.

Happy coding!